# Firebase profiling for a specific device?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cli

As per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/profile) we can measure the performance of our Firebase Realtime Database with the database profiler tool. Since my app is in live and I want to check bandwidth data by traversing all over the application only on my device. Can I do this using database profiler tool or any other way to do it?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you mean by "check bandwidth data by traversing all over the application only on my device".  Please edit the question to be more clear about the problem you're trying to solve and where you are stuck with that.

Comment: If I run `firebase database:profile` it will measure/count all current operations in DB. What I want is I need to measure operations for one specific device(Since my app is live on AppStore) - for testing purpose.

Comment: That sounds like information that would be helpful to put in the question itself. You can use the edit like at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Answer to what you asked is below, but it sounds a bit like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). So if the profiler is not the solution after all, I recommend posting a separate question about the actual problem that you think the profiler may help you solve, to see if we can help with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database profiler runs on the entire database instance. There is no configuration option or API to run the profiler for a single device.

If you want to profile the behavior of a single device, consider setting up a secondary database (in the same project or in its own project) and running the profiler on that instead.